# How to pin point a memory leak in a heap dump using jhat/jvisualvm tool?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

How to  pin point a memory leak in a heap dump using jhat/jvisualvm tool?

I have a heap dump of our application generated using jmap during an "OutOfMemoryError:Java Heap Space error". I used jhat to analyse the dump but the info is too huge and I could not find where the memory leak occurred.Please help me in pin-pointing the objects that caused memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Visual VM will show you that the perm gen is filled, which means OOM error.

When you get that [heap dump](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/heapdump.html), you'll be able to see the object with the most instances.  That should give you a clue as to the culprit.

Comment: You can get OOME for plenty of reasons other than perm gen filling up. Most likely is the old generation filling up if using a generational GC. But also if garbage collection takes too long, etc.

Comment: I cited one example among many.  The point is that Visual VM will help identify all of them.